# using pst-all results in a warning in dvipdf

Tags: pstricks, article, ghostscript

Feeding the file mwe.tex containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

to `latex mwe && dvipdf mwe` results in

```
%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY
```

on a tty. The same warning emerges when running `latex mwe && dvips mwe && ps2pdf mwe.ps`.

What have I done wrong so that I need to be warned, who is the culprit, and what to do?

Here is some versioning information:

```
pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
article 2021/10/04 v1.4n
pst-all 2008/01/01
ghostscript 9.55.0
```

Cf. also http://bugs.debian.org/1003255 .

Comment: oh so it is sorry I forgot about that one, it doesn't come with texlive, I read your q as the texlive dvipdfm, I'll delete the first comment, you would have to edit the script to add the specified option to gs

Comment: Sorry, I corrected myself. Not gs is called directly, but dvips first. The result is then fed to gs.

Comment: dvips makes postscript then gs (or rather its ps2pdf script) is called to make pdf, it is gs that has changed removing the transparency operations then forcing an option to put them back

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The exact contents of dvipdf is in http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/ghostscript/ghostscript_9.55.0~dfsg-3_amd64.deb

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can surely pass the option `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY`
 to `dvipdf`, and the warning then goes away. My point is that if the document contain NO transparency operators at all (in fact, no drawings at all), the generated intermediate Postscript file (a pipe in my `dvipdf`) shouldn't have the corresponding transparency-related stuff at all, should it?

Comment: the pstricks header includes transparency ops in its definitions and triggers this every time, it's an intentional feature from the gs developers nothing we can do about it from the tex side other than arrange the option is applied, and that dvipdf script isn't under texlive control so there's nothing we can do about that at all

Comment: I see. Could pstricks issue transparency definitions only when needed, hypothetically speaking? In other terms, should I ask pstricks developers?

Comment: I haven't looked in detail at the pstricks sources since the 1990s so don't ask me:-)

Comment: @GeekestGeek:  That behaviour will not be changed! PSTricks has no internal check if someone uses the `opacity` or `strokeopacity` options. You can use instead `lualatex`  then you do not need the `ghostscript` run.

Comment: @user187802 This request is for large old documents that have already so much of PSTricks in them that they are stuck to `pstricks` and `latex`. In the particular case of my interest, the large old document uses NO transparency: no opacity, no strokeopacity, nothing of the kind. For such documents, generating Postscript features that the developers of `gs` probably consider nonstandard might be strange.

Answer (score 0):

As you have read in the comments you can't remove the transparency (the fault is gs's in any case).

You can reduce the routine a bit by making use of some utility, for example using `arara`:

Clasic `latex>dvips>ps2pdf`

```latex
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf: { options : [ -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY  -dNOSAFER] }
% arara: clean: { extensions : [ aux, log, dvi, ps ] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

If you prefer to use `lualatex`

```latex
% arara: lualatex
% arara: clean: { extensions : [ aux, log ] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Or prefer to use `xelatex`

```latex
% arara: xelatex: { options: [ '-output-driver', 'xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -E -q' ] }
% arara: clean: { extensions : [ aux, log ] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

or from a terminal (need update TeX Live):

```bash
$ lualatex file.tex 
$ xelatex-unsafe file.tex
```

you can also use `latexmk` and create a configuration file for the process.

I hope this is helpful

Regards

Comment: Thanks! I think the fault (or, more neutrally speaking, the *burden*) is less with `gs` and more with PStricks. IMHO, if the LaTeX document has no transparency-related stuff at all (if no drawings at all, the more so), the generated intermediate Postscript file shouldn't have the corresponding transparency-related stuff either. The burden of detecting transparency or its absence in Postscript (i.e., by `gs`) is probably algorithmically hard due to nontrivial input to `gs` and, generally speaking, Rice's theorem.